# DateTimePicker value from Excel

Tags: c#

I am wondering if it is possible to set the value of a DateTimePicker from a queried row in excel. I have tried different ways of doing it but have never came close and anyone help?

Also it all is displayed on a windows form

Comment: What do you get when reading the row in excel?

Comment: I can't, When I use oledbDataReader it mentions about the data types are different. I tried to use Tostring() and set the datetimepicker value as the string but no luck.

Comment: Can you post your query string?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void ReadAndWriteToExcel()
    {
        string myPath = @"C:\Excel.xls";
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(myPath);
        if (!fi.Exists)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("file doesn't exists!");
        }
        else
        {
            var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            var workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath);
            Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;

            // To write to excel
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = worksheet.Cells[1, 1] as Range;
            DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            range.NumberFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy";
            range.Value2 = dt;

            // To read,
            var date = worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value;
            Console.Out.WriteLine(date.ToString());

            workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();
        }
    }
```

you must add "Microsoft.Office.Core" and "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" references to your project and use them.